# Drawing this complex set in the plane

Tags: complex-analysis

I am stuck trying to draw the set of complex $z$ such that $|z^2 - 1| < 1$.

I tried writing $z^2 - 1 = (z-1)(z+1)$ but it didn't help me. Perhaps I am missing something.

I also thought of writing $|z^2 - 1| = (z^2 - 1)(\overline{z}^2 - 1) < 1$ which didn't help me either.

Finally, writing either $z = x + iy$ and $z = e^{i\varphi}$ didn't help me either.

I have run out of ideas. I know $|z-1|<1$ would be a disk centered at $(1,0)$ of radius $1$ and $|z^2-1|<1$ should be the square root of that disk. But it's not clear to me what the square root of a disk looks like.

> Please could someone explain to me how I can determine and draw this
>   set?

Comment: The boundary of this set should be the points satisfying $|z^2-1|=1\implies z^2-1=e^{i\phi}$ which can be solved for $z$ as a parametric function of $\phi$. Sketching that seems like a good place to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$z = re^{i\varphi}$$
$$z^2-1 = r^2e^{2i\varphi}-1= r^2\cos( 2\varphi)-1+ir^2\sin( 2\varphi) $$

$$|z^2-1 |^2= (r^2\cos( 2\varphi)-1)^2+(r^2\sin( 2\varphi))^2 $$
$$|z^2-1 |<1 \implies |z^2-1 |^2<1
\\ \implies (r^2\cos( 2\varphi)-1)^2+(r^2\sin( 2\varphi))^2 <1
\\ \implies r^4\cos^2( 2\varphi)-2r^2\cos( 2\varphi)+1+(r^4\sin^2( 2\varphi)) < 1 
\\ \implies  r^2(r^2-2\cos( 2\varphi))<0$$

So the region you require is the inside of the polar plot of $ r= \sqrt{2\cos( 2\varphi) }  $ ( looks like $\infty$)

Comment: Regarding it looking like $\infty$: More precisely, it's the [lemniscate of Bernoulli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemniscate_of_Bernoulli).

Comment: Thank you, this really helps me! Shouldn't it be $r = \sqrt{2\cos (2\varphi)}$? How can I see that this looks like $\infty$ without using a graphing tool? Do I have any chance of figuring it out with just pencil and paper?

Comment: I have corrected my error . As for pencil and paper evaluate $r(\varphi)$ for $\varphi=0, \pm \pi/8, \pm 3 \pi/8 $ etc. the figure should take shape.